# Is there a nice proof that $123456789098765432111$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

The mathematician Charles Weibel asks on his [home page](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/) the following "fun question": How can you prove that 123456789098765432111 is a prime number? (He notes the fact

> $$12345678987654321 = 111111111 \times 111111111$$

which is of course well-known.)

By "proof", I assume he means something more humanly illuminating than asking a computer program. I haven't a clue what he has in mind. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Thanks; let me know if you flesh out a more precise argument.

Comment: my attempt: $\frac{123456789098765432111 - 11}{100} = 1234567890987654321$  don't know where to go from there... hopefully it helps, somehow

Comment: Relevant: [primality certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate).

Comment: Note that $123456789009876543211$ is prime as well, and $1111111111\cdot 1111111111=1234567900987654321$

Comment: @dtldarek: Yes. This is not something I've studied much, although I am aware of (the existence of) the related AKS algorithm. It would be interesting if this leads to certification a human could work out by pencil in a page or two.

Comment: @abiessu: As I tried to indicate, I'd like something conceptual and not horribly brute force (because knowing Charles Weibel, I'll bet he has something more conceptual in mind). Although I am not a number theorist, I am a mathematician and I'd be willing to tolerate a fair dose of number-theoretic sophistication in an answer. I'd be interested if the little observation he made were not just a red herring he threw in there just for kicks.

Comment: Maybe try something using base $2$? If the last three digits of a number in base $10$ are $111$ then its last three digits in base $2$ are as well. (I'm stumped...)

Comment: This sounds like a great candidate for the classic 'Fermat's little theorem' certificates, testing the primality of $p$ by factoring $p-1$ and then checking powers of small primes to the various divisors of $p-1$, $\bmod p$.  Volume 4 of The Art Of Computer Programming goes over the method with a couple of illustrations; that would be the first thing I'd look at. (But my copies are at home and I can't easily get at them right now. :/ )

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sadly, I don't have volume 4, but your comment is in spirit very similar to ronno's answer below. Yes, you're right -- and methodologically I see nothing wrong with that type of approach -- but I'm still wondering why Weibel thinks it's a "fun question", if there's not a particularly "fun solution" lying around. (But maybe there isn't one?)

Comment: @user43208 Minor correction to my comment - I meant chapter 4, in vol. 2; the coffee hasn't realy kicked in yet. :-)  I agree, though; I feel like there's a version of this approach that's much 'cuter' in its calculations than the brute-forcery offered below, but I'm not sure what it would be offhand.

Comment: 11111111110^2 - 1000000^2 + 11 = 123456789098765432111 , for whatever that is worth.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is humanly illuminating, but I believe it is humanly checkable. The following is a Pratt certificate, assuming primality for primes $\leq 100$:

```
123456789098765432111, 7, 123456789098765432111-1 = 2*5*63493*322997*601991891
  63493, 2, 63493-1 = 2*2*3*11*13*37
  322997, 2, 322997-1 = 2*2*80749
    80749, 2, 80749-1 = 2*2*3*3*2243
      2243, 2, 2243-1 = 2*19*59
  601991891, 2, 601991891-1 = 2*5*191*315179
    191, 19, 191-1 = 2*5*19
      315179, 2, 315179-1 = 2*59*2671
        2671, 7, 2671-1 = 2*3*5*89
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll give you an upvote for it, but I'd like to see if there are some other ideas on this... Chuck Weibel called it a "fun question", meaning I'd guess it also has a "fun solution". But in principle I accept this type of answer as perfectly reasonable, from a methodological point of view.

Answer (score 3):

**More Fun with Numbers**

The [number](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/) `12345678987654321=111111111x111111111` is mentioned in the OP. And, believe it or not,  $1234567898765432111$ **is a prime number too!!!**

You have to believe it! The following $maxima$ output shall demonstrate this using [Pratt's primality certificat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate).

`(%i1) m:1234567898765432111;a:29;power_mod(a,m-1,m);factor(m-1); makelist(power_mod(a,(m-1)/p,m),p,map(first,ifactors(m-1)));

(%o1) 1234567898765432111

(%o2) 29

(%o3) 1

(%o4) 2*5*11*11223344534231201

(%o5) [1234567898765432110, 972745681039223016, 1223153431857342200, 1089307852892054661]`

- `%i1` is the input line.
- `%o1`is the output showing the modul $m$, the number that we check if it is prime.
- `%o2` is an outputline showing the number $a$ we exponate.
- `%o3` is the output of $a^{m-1} \pmod{m}$. It should be $1$ if $m$ is a prime. But it could be $1$ even if $M$ is composite.
- `%o4` is the factorisation of $m-1$ and
- `%o5` are the numbers $a^{\frac{m-1}{p}}$ for all prime factors of $m-1$

The factors $2$,$5$ and $11$ are primes but it is not obvious that $11223344534231201$ is a prime number. so we add a proof that $11223344534231201$ is a prime too:

`(%i1) m:11223344534231201;a:3;power_mod(a,m-1,m);factor(m-1); makelist(power_mod(a,(m-1)/p,m),p,map(first,ifactors(m-1)));

(%o1) 11223344534231201

(%o2) 3

(%o3) 1

(%o4) 2^5*5^2*7*73*101*109^2*137*167

(%o5) [11223344534231200, 7251767246727978,1687389182360412, 5679768249246961, 2181793601204580, 9078160829860754, 8735272021960592, 1320423471360269]`

Because it is easy to check that $2,5,7,73,109,137,167$ are primes we are finished.

( both $a=29$ and $a=3$ can be replaced by the larger but funnier number $1111111$ int the certificates)

But how does this primality certificate work?

The following is well known:

- all residue classes $a$ that are relatively prime to the module $m$ constitute a multiplicative  group $\pmod{m}$
- If $a^{m-1} \pmod{m}$ is not equal to $1$ then $m$ could not be a prime because this contradicts [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).
- $\text{ord}_{m-1}(a)$  is the smallest power $e$ such that $a^{e} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, it  is a divisor of every such $e$. Especially of $\phi(m)$.
- if $a^{m-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ then  $\text{ord}_{m-1}(a)$ is a divisor of $m-1$. If it is a proper divisor of $m-1$ it must be a divisor of $\frac{m-1}{p}$ for a prime $p$ dividing $m$. Then $a^\frac{m-1}{p} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for such a $p$
- all the residue classes $a,a^2,...,a^{\text{ord}(a)}$ are pairwise different

So if $\text{ord}(a)=m-1$ and $\phi(m)=m-1$ and therefore $m$ is a prime.

[@ronno](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492285/proof-that-123456789098765432111-is-prime/510230#510230) would note this certificate  as

```
1234567898765432111,29,1234567898765432111-1=2*5*11*11223344534231201
  11223344534231201,3,11223344534231201-1=2^5*5^2*7*73*101*109^2*137*167
    167,...
    137,...
    109,...
    101,...
```

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. Thanks for answering though.